# How to write each row of a pandas dataframe into a new line single text file - each df value has start and end position to be written on on each line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, file-handling

I have a huge dataframe and I want to write each row of dataframe as a newline into a single text file (excluding column names)
I have a structure file which indicates Start and End position of the value of each column to be written on the single line. (Each line has to start from position 0 and ends on position 1841)

I have written the following code, however, it overwrites a single line with the data of every next dataframe row. In the end, after processing the full file, I only get one row of data.

```
min_line_pos = estructura['POSICION INICIAL'].min()
max_line_pos = estructura['POSICION FINAL'].max()
with open('test_conversion.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for ind in range(pickled_data.shape[0]):
        empty_string = (' '*max_line_pos).encode('latin-1')
        f.write(empty_string)
        for i, r in estructura.iterrows():
            to_write = str(pickled_data.astype(str).iloc[ind][r.VARIABLE]).encode('latin-1')
            position = r['POSICION INICIAL']-1
            f.seek(position)
            if i+1 == estructura.shape[0]:
                f.write(to_write + ('\r\n').encode('latin-1'))
            else:
                f.write(to_write)
```

How to force make it shift the f position to the next line (but still starts with 0th index)? Any help is appreciated. Also, if we can optimise this process, as I have 100s of millions of rows in the dataframe. Thank you!

Comment: are you using the append mode for your open()? is it possible that because it is in "w" everytime you call write() it overwrites whatever is currently in your file?

Comment: I just tried 'ab' instead of 'wb' and the problem with it is that it appends empty_string = (' '*max_line_pos).encode('latin-1') in the beginning and the structure goes haywire. because in wb due to printing empty string ensures the positioning of written values